# is there any way to make my code cleaner?

Tags: python, regex, text

I am writing a python script to extract important information from a old text file (it's an a2l file actually, so I'll named it a2l in my code) and append everything to a new text file. This code works properly, but I'm sure there are better and cleaner ways to construct it (I'm not really experienced in text manipulation or regex, but I'm eager to learn).

The old text file (a2l) is kinda lengthy so I'll try to explain how my code is works in short. Basically there are two groups, GROUP1 and GROUP2. My goal is to extract the name properties of them (stored as "val") and generate a more reading-friendly name (stored as "name") according to the original name. next, I want to do some simple classification according to either their data types or their names.

This is an example of the old text file:

```
/begin GROUP1
  /* Name                   */      FirstElem_Val 
  /* Long Identifier        */      "first input value to be configured"
  /* Type                   */      VALUE
  /* ECU Address            */      0x080136c6
  /* Record Layout          */      Scalar_BOOLEAN 
  /* Maximum Difference     */      0
  /* Conversion Method      */      ECU_boolean_0_0_1_0
  /* Lower Limit            */      0
  /* Upper Limit            */      1
  SYMBOL_LINK                       "FirstElem_Val" 0      
/end GROUP1

/begin GROUP1
  /* Name                   */      FirstElem_Err 
  /* Long Identifier        */      "first input error to be configured"
  /* Type                   */      VALUE
  /* ECU Address            */      0x080136c7
  /* Record Layout          */      Scalar_BOOLEAN 
  /* Maximum Difference     */      0
  /* Conversion Method      */      ECU_boolean_0_0_1_0
  /* Lower Limit            */      0
  /* Upper Limit            */      1
  SYMBOL_LINK                       "FirstElem_Err" 0      
/end GROUP1

/begin GROUP1
  /* Name                   */      SecondElem 
  /* Long Identifier        */      "second input to be configured"
  /* Type                   */      VALUE
  /* ECU Address            */      0x080134ec
  /* Record Layout          */      Scalar_FLOAT32_IEEE 
  /* Maximum Difference     */      0
  /* Conversion Method      */      ECU_single_second_0_0_1_0
  /* Lower Limit            */      0
  /* Upper Limit            */      10
  SYMBOL_LINK                       "SecondElem" 0      
/end GROUP1

/begin GROUP2
  /* Name        */      ThirdElem_Val
  /* Long identifier     */      ""
  /* Data type       */      UBYTE
  /* Conversion method     */      ECU_uint8_0_0_1_0
  /* Resolution (Not used)  */     0
  /* Accuracy (Not used)    */     0
  /* Lower limit            */      0
  /* Upper limit            */      255
  ECU_ADDRESS               0x0801355a
  SYMBOL_LINK               "ThirdElem_Val" 0
 /end GROUP2

 /begin GROUP2
  /* Name        */      ThirdElem_Sta
  /* Long identifier     */      ""
  /* Data type       */      UBYTE
  /* Conversion method     */      ECU_SignalStatusEnum_0_0_1_0
  /* Resolution (Not used)  */     0
  /* Accuracy (Not used)    */     0
  /* Lower limit            */      0
  /* Upper limit            */      3
  ECU_ADDRESS               0x08013698
  SYMBOL_LINK               "ThirdElem_Sta" 0
 /end GROUP2

 /begin GROUP2
  /* Name        */      FourthElem
  /* Long identifier     */      ""
  /* Data type       */      UWORD
  /* Conversion method     */      ECU_uint16_0_0_1_0
  /* Resolution (Not used)  */     0
  /* Accuracy (Not used)    */     0
  /* Lower limit            */      0
  /* Upper limit            */      65535
  ECU_ADDRESS               0x080135a6
  SYMBOL_LINK               "FourthElem" 0
 /end GROUP2
```

Here's my lengthy python code

```
import re
import os


def putSpace(line):
    return re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", line)

def generator(file):
    char_count = 0 #characteristics
    meas_count = 0 #measurement
    with open(file, 'r+') as a2l:
        for line in a2l:   
            generated = open('new.txt','a+')
            if line.find('/begin GROUP1')>=0:
                char_count += 1
                name_line = next(a2l, '').strip()
                val = name_line.replace('/* Name                   */      ','')
                name = name_line.replace('/* Name                   */      ','')
                name = putSpace(name)
                # a bunch of replacements to make it readable
                name = name.replace('_','')
                name = name.replace('Elem','Element')
                name = name.replace('Val','Value')
                name = name.replace('Err','Error')
                for i in range(4):
                    char_type = next(a2l, '').strip() #record layout
                    if 'FLOAT32' in char_type:
                        generated_out = 'text: \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (name,val)
                        generated.write(str(generated_out)+'\n')                         
                    elif 'Scalar_BOOLEAN' in char_type:
                        #first element has two types
                        if 'Val' in val:
                            generated_out = 'bool-HL \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (name,val)
                            generated.write(str(generated_out)+'\n')
                        elif 'Err' in val:
                            generated_out = 'bool-err \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (name,val)
                            generated.write(str(generated_out)+'\n')

            elif line.find('/begin GROUP2')>=0:
                meas_count += 1
                name_line = next(a2l, '').strip()
                val = name_line.replace('/* Name        */      ','')
                name = name_line.replace('/* Name        */      ','')
                name = putSpace(name)
                # a bunch of replacements to make it readable
                name = name.replace('_','')
                name = name.replace('Elem','Element')
                name = name.replace('Val','Value')
                name = name.replace('Sta','Status')
                for i in range(3):
                    meas_type = next(a2l, '').strip()
                    if 'uint' in meas_type:
                        generated_out = 'text: \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (name,val)
                        generated.write(str(generated_out)+'\n')
                    elif 'Enum' in meas_type:
                        generated_out = 'enum: \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (name,val)
                        generated.write(str(generated_out)+'\n')


    print('group1: ',char_count,' group2: ',meas_count)




path = r'C:[file directory]'
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in sorted(dirs):
   #print(file)
   #if file==""
   try:
     generator(file)
   except:
     print('not found')
```

This is my output that shouldn't be changed.

```
bool-HL 'First Element Value' 'FirstElem_Val'
bool-err 'First Element Error' 'FirstElem_Err'
text: 'Second Element' 'SecondElem'
text: 'Third Element Value' 'ThirdElem_Val'
enum: 'Third Element Status' 'ThirdElem_Sta'
text: 'Fourth Element' 'FourthElem'
```

Comment: You can check : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh I didn't know this website! Thanks for recommending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complex text processing always looks approximately as your code. A couple pieces of advise as you asked for.

Use the “f” prefixed strings to format instead of the “%”. It’s much clearer and safe. For example,

```py
generated_out = 'bool-HL \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (name,val)` # not one of the best way
generated_out = f"bool-HL '{name}' '{val}'"`          # the same, but a little better
```

I used double quotes for enclosing the whole string in order to get rid of necessity to use backslashes before single quotes inside the string (by the way, they are forbidden in “f-strings”). And I used the “f” prefix to format the string “just in place” according to the scope (it automatically retrieves `name` and `val` from the current scope).

Here is the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Here is a good article: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Then, I’d write two-three local micro functions (like your `putSpace`) for the clarity, for example:

```py
def store():
    generated.write(generated_out+'\n') # “str()-conversion” doesn’t need because “generated_out” is really a string

def change(source, changes):
    result = source
    for old, new in changes.items():
        result = result.replace(old, new)
    return result

# and somewhere in the code, instead of…
name = name.replace('_','')
name = name.replace('Elem','Element')
name = name.replace('Val','Value')
name = name.replace('Sta','Status')

# …you can write something like this
name = change(name, {
    '_': '',
    'Elem': 'Element',
    'Val': 'Value',
    'Sta': 'Status',
})
```

And I’d give shorter names for the variables, for example, “output” for “generated_out”.

Good luck and feel free to ask questions!